# checking each letter to see if it contains all letters needed, this code isn´t working

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I need to check if all the letters that form a given word are contained inside a given string. I´ve tried something but isn´t working:

```
def check(texto, control):
    for letra in control:
        if texto.find(letra) == control.find(letra):
            return control + " is not here"
        else:
            return control + " is here!"
```

> print check('jshdgfyrgj', 'Correo')

Should return "Correo is not here"

> print check('cfgotyrrtepo', 'Correo')

Should return "Correo is here!"

It currently returns correo is here in all cases. Whats wrong with my code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple issues - one, you expect the function to ignore case differences, but don't tell it to do so. - 'c' is not 'C'.

For checking to see whether a letter is in a string it's often better to use `letter in text_string` rather than the `str.find()` method. Be sure you understand what find returns - check out the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

In the example below I use `letter in set(text_string)` - this only checks the letters of `text_string` once if there are duplicates. For small strings this won't make much of a difference in performance.

You can use the `all` function to do a bunch of boolean checks.

```
def check(text, control):
    # Set both strings to lower case, since we're ignoring case
    text = text.lower()
    control = control.lower()
    # Check that each character in control is in text
    return all((c in text for c in set(control)))

>>> check('jshdgfyrgj', 'Correo')
2: False
>>> check('cfgotyrrtepo', 'Correo')
3: True
```

Comment: You say it's better to use `letter in text_string` and then use the equivalent `letter in set(text_string)`. Need to explain why...

Comment: you can just `return all((c in text for c in set(control)))`

Comment: Actually, another reason one might want to use `letter in set(text_string)` instead of `letter in text_string` is because the time complexity of searching a hash table is O(1) vs O(n) for a linear search. However to do this also entails the overhead of constructing the `set` object, so in this case it could actually slow things down...

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like:

```
def check(texto, control):
    texto = [letter for letter in texto]
    while texto:
        for letra in control:
            if letra in texto:
                texto.remove(letra)
            else:
                return False
    return True
```

this ensures repeated letters are repeated in texto also.

e.g.

```
>>> check('abc','bac')
True
>>> check('abc','bacc')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter:

```
...
return all([letter in texto for letter in control])
```

If order is important:

```
...
texto_modified = "".join([letter for letter in texto if letter in control])
return texto_modified == control
```

Comment: inner list is not required in `all()`.